# Move to one fragment to another fragment of different container activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an container activity which will contain the fragments which will be added to this container when my bottom nav bar is navigating. Now I want to go to one of this fragment to another fragment which will replace another different activity by set on click listener of a cardview.
I am new fragment so I dont understand how to do that. Hope someone will help me.

Comment: Would you mind to provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried so far? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You approach is wrong. You cannot navigate from one activity fragment to another activity fragment. The correct way will be to have single activity with multiple fragments inside. Using [Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) will be the best way of navigation.

Comment: Why this approach is wrong? Will you please explain me little bit of it?